# How to add createStackNavigator inside ImageBackround of view to have common background image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-native-navigation

I am trying to import createStackNavigator from an external file and add it inside ImageBackground of View so that I can have common flow of backround image from top to bottom but I am getting errors like
 TypeError: No "routes" found in navigation state

Code:

```
      <View style={styles1}>
        <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg' }} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
 <componentNavigator style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} navigation={navigation} />
   <View></View>

        </ImageBackground>
        {/*</ImageBackground>*/}
      </View >
```

To fix the above issue I added 
static router = AccountsNavigator.router; // added it below constructor

Then I am getting Connot readt propery 'router' of undefined
I am not sure how to fix it, even if it fixed will it take the flow og background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, by adding headerTransparent: true inside navigationOptions, I can able to achieve transparent background though I had to position the below container with position: absolute